# Recording Video in UYVY codec in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-processing, avi

I have a camera from e-con systems which supports UYVU codec video recording. When I use their own software (QTCam) to record a video it records in avi format with YUY2 Codec, which the video opens and runs in VLC perfectly.

[image]

Now I tried recording the video through Opencv VideoWrtiter().
I used this command to set the Camera property to read UYVY Codec video.

```
camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC,CV_FOURCC('U','Y','V','Y'));
```

and also used VideoWriter to record the video in an AVI file format.

```
video1.open("/home/camera1UYVY.avi",CV_FOURCC('Y','U','Y','2'),30,s1,true);
```

The feed from the camera is working, I checked with imshow(). But the recored video is not playing in VLC as it worked for the one recorded from QTCam.

Even the recoded opencv recorded has the same codec

[image]

My Code goes below

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

VideoCapture camera1;
Mat frame1;

camera1.open(0);

camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC,CV_FOURCC('U','Y','V','Y'));


camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1280);
camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,720);



cout << "FPS:" << camera1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) << endl;

camera1.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,30);

cout << "FPS:" << camera1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS) << endl;

cout << "Camera -1 Codec: " << (int)camera1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC) << endl;


VideoWriter video1;

cout << camera1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH) << endl;
cout << camera1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT) << endl;
Size s1 = Size((int)camera1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH),(int)camera1.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));


video1.open("/home/camera1UYVY.avi",CV_FOURCC('Y','U','Y','2'),30,s1,true);


while(!camera1.isOpened()){
    cout << "Camera not opened" << endl;
    continue;
}
while(1){

    if(!video1.isOpened()){
        cout << "Error opening video" << endl;
    }
    camera1.read(frame1);
    imshow("Display1",frame1);
    video1.write(frame1);
    cout << frame1.data << endl;
    if(waitKey(1) == 27){
        break;
    }
}
video1.release();
camera1.release();
return 0;
```

}
please tell me where I'm going wrong. I want to record a uncompressed video from the camera and save it as a video file(which opens in a VLC or any other video player)

Comment: Not sure if I understand this - but I am no expert on video. You appear to be reading `UYVY` data and writing the exact same unmodified data and suddenly claiming it is `YUY2`...?

Comment: Actually, I'm reading UYVY data and writing in Avi file using UYVY and also using YUV2 codec. Both gave the same result. It doesn't play on any media player.

Comment: I would start by checking what ``CAP_PROP_FORMAT`` and ``CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB`` are set to.

Comment: Could you create your `Mat frame1` inside the `while(1)` and also move the `imshow` after the `write` and see if that helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenCV seems to have an issue writing yuv422p formats to avi. Try this instead:

```
video1.open("/home/camera1UYVY.avi",CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V'),30,s1,true);
```

This is a yuv420p pixel format, which means you lose some precision in the vertical U and V planes, but it will still be uncompressed video.